# tf.keras.layers.Conv2D get kernel values

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

How do I get the Kernel values from  `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D`?

Here is my code:

```
#input image is 5 X 5 and 1 channel 
input_shape = (1, 1, 5, 5)

x = tf.random.normal(input_shape) 

y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( 
   2, 2, activation= tf.nn.relu, input_shape=input_shape, 
   data_format='channels_first')(x)
```

I am using tf version 2.2

I have tried `y.get_weights()` and this didn't work I got:

```
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' 
object has no attribute 'get_weights'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually store the layer in a variable. In your code, `y` is the *result* of the convolution. For example

```
input_shape = (1, 1, 5, 5)

x = tf.random.normal(input_shape) 

conv_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D( 
   2, 2, activation= tf.nn.relu, input_shape=input_shape, 
   data_format='channels_first')
y = conv_layer(x)
```

Now you should be able to use `conv_layer.get_weights()`.